# UITableViewCell _tableView property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a custom `UITableViewCell` and I'm hoping to access the parent tableView from with the cell subclass. I was in the process of creating a custom init method that allows me to specify the tableview, but came across an error.

I tried declaring an iVar of `__weak UITableView *_tableView;` however, I was given an error stating it was a duplicate declaration. I looked into the `UITableViewCell` header file, and sure enough, there is a declaration of

```
@private
    UITableView *_tableView;
```

This is great as I assume iOS will be setting this for me, however I want to know if I'm allowed to use this, or if this is one of those things that will get my app rejected. There is no documentation on this and I've not found any mention of if anywhere online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right not to try to access the private ivar. I'd suggest not bothering to pass in the superview, either, but just use what's available to the table cell to find its enclosing `tableView`

UIView+mytable.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (mytable)

- (UITableView *)mySuperTableView;

@end
```

UIView+mytable.m:

```
#import "UIView+dsltable.h"

@implementation UIView (dsltable)

- (UITableView *)mySuperTableView
{
    if ( [self isKindOfClass: [UITableView class]] )
        return (UITableView *)self;
    return [self.superview mySuperTableView];
}

@end
```

Comment: Oo I like this approach! Very nice :)

Comment: Btw, thanks to how Objective-C handles messaging nil, this will return nil outside of a tableview with no modification. :)

Comment: Ah excellent stuff! Definitely gonna take this approach then, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access the undocumented private ivar. You either need to add your ivar with a different name or get the table view by getting the cell's superview.

Comment: ha yeah I realised I couldn't access it just as I posted :P I was just curious though